how to deploy on the ACI using the latest docker as it doesnt azure ACL
I want to deploy my images on the ACI to run it, as I was earlier using the Docker command line to do the same, but I see that the support for all the public clouds has been removed from the docker command line, so is there a proper way to do this?
I tried using the docker command line but it didn't work, so needed a solution for this.

Have you checked this- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/quickstart-docker-cli#quickstart-deploy-a-container-instance-in-azure-using-the-docker-cli ? Also, did you consider using Azure CLI for deploying image in ACI?

I wouldn't say that support for all public clouds has been removed from the Docker command line. What has changed is Docker used to have built-in commands (like docker-machine) that directly interfaced with specific cloud providers (like AWS, Azure, etc). This direct integration has been removed or deprecated in recent Docker versions. But yes, I got what you are trying to say.
As I mentioned in comment, apart from this   Quickstart: Deploy a container instance in Azure using the Docker CLI approach, you can consider using Azure CLI.
Install Azure CLI on your local machine and from powershell (if windows) or cmd (if mac), do az login. You can even directly use the az cli from the azure portal.
once logged in, first ensure your docker desktop is running and then docker login, pull your image (I am showing with a hello world image).
 docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld

Next ensure you have created an azure container registry so that you can tag and push this image to the registry
az acr create --resource-group yourresourcegroup --name arkoregistry --sku Basic

az acr login --name arkoregistry

docker tag mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld arkoregistry.azurecr.io/aci-helloworld:latest

docker push arkoregistry.azurecr.io/aci-helloworld:latest


Once Image is available inside your acr,

deploy your aci
az container create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name aci-demo-west \
  --image arkoregistry.azurecr.io/aci-helloworld:latest \
  --cpu 1 \
  --memory 1 \
  --registry-login-server arkoregistry.azurecr.io \
  --registry-username arkoregistry \
  --registry-password xyA5qZh8ngEqFuihg3Rg+/tTRXncBjNSEiYNpD1CpB+ACRD/HGSH \
  --dns-name-label aci-demo-west \
  --ports 80 \
  --location westus

There is this service principal option as well-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-using-azure-container-registry
But you can simplify it by using just username and password from your acr as I showed


Done. Now check

Your ACI is up and running

